# Advice for Web-based Remote Build System

Tags: web-services, jenkins, automation

I'm interested in setting up a remote build system at work, initially for internal use, potentially for some customers going forward. We need to compile library code on several different machines (PC, Mac) and with multiple compilers, and it can be a real pain trying to get access to a full set. This is not our main build system, which is Jenkins-based and uses an approach that is not easily modified for the purpose envisaged here.

The idea would be that you could post your source to a website with some basic build parameters, it would compile the code and you could then download the generated code. Ideally users could pick which version of the underlying software they compiled their libraries against. I envisage it being supported by a virtual machine.

Reason I'm posting is that I don't really want to roll-my-own as much as possible - longer term it has maintenance implications - and would prefer something as pre-existing as possible. Obviously one would expect some adaptation in terms of scripting.

Any suggestions? It would have to be supported on Mac and PC at absolute minimum.

Comment: I believe you can trigger a build by commit - so standard GIT, etc. should work.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10014380/1662973

Comment: Take a look at Atlassian Jira in combination with Stash (GIT) and Bamboo (Build)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something you could do by creating a parameterized Jenkins job (the build params given as input to your web frontent could be passed on to the job, perhaps via the Jenkins API). Personally, I would see if you could skip the step of creating a new webfrontend, and have users pass their build params directly to Jenkins.

To support downloading the resulting compiled code, you could have the Jenkins job archive the build as an artifact. Users could then download the files from the result page for that individual build.

As for how to make a Jenkins job accept source code to compile as input, perhaps you could use branches in your CM system? Your users could push their code to a branch, and then pass the branch as a build param. Otherwise, you might be able to use the file parameter feature of Jenkins.