# How can we build a job on every commit to svn in jenkins ios build

Tags: ios, jenkins, version-control, build, auto-build

I would like to build my jenkins job on every commit happened to svn repository, Can you guys please suggest me how could we do ?

Comment: This question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014252/jenkins-ci-how-to-trigger-builds-on-svn-commit